# Why is my react-bootstrap button import not working?

Tags: reactjs, web, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I installed react-bootstrap using the following command (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)):

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.6.0
```

I proceeded to import it as follows:

```
import { Input } from "antd";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
```

I used it as follows:

```
<Input
    placeholder="Placeholder"
/>
<Button>Sign Up</Button>
```

However, adding the button breaks the page. It works fine when the button is removed. Can someone please help me out?

Here is a screenshot of the console:[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYosq.png)

Here is the entire code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Input } from "antd";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import _ from "lodash";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default class SignUpPage extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            email: "",
            firstPassword: "",
            secondPassword: "",
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { username, email, firstPassword, secondPassword } = this.state;

        const confirmPasswordDisabled =
            _.get(firstPassword, ["length"], 0) === 0;

        return (
            <>
                <div
                    className="container"
                    style={{
                        margin: "auto",
                        width: "400px",
                        paddingTop: "200px",
                    }}
                >
                    <Input
                        placeholder="Username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            this.setState({ username: e.target.value })
                        }
                        style={{
                            margin: "5px",
                        }}
                    />
                    <Input
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
                        }
                        style={{
                            margin: "5px",
                        }}
                    />
                    <Input
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={firstPassword}
                        type="password"
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            this.setState({ firstPassword: e.target.value })
                        }
                        style={{
                            margin: "5px",
                        }}
                    />
                    <Input
                        placeholder="Confirm Password"
                        value={secondPassword}
                        type="password"
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            this.setState({ secondPassword: e.target.value })
                        }
                        disabled={confirmPasswordDisabled}
                        style={{
                            margin: "5px",
                        }}
                    />
                    <Button color="primary">Sign Up</Button>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting?

Comment: Check if `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` is installed by running ` npm ls`. Also make sure you have [imported css from node_modules](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#css)

Comment: @TobiasS I'm adding a screenshot of the console in the description

Comment: Ah oke, can you edit you post and add the entire file where you want to use Button.

Comment: @TobiasS That is done.

Comment: In the fourth import statement change `import { Button } from "react-bootstrap"` to `import { Button } from "react-bootstrap/Button"`

Comment: That gave a webpack warning since Button is a default export so I changed it to
`import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'`
It didn't work.

Comment: Can you put `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in your index.js file instead of your component file? And keep the `/Button` in the `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'`.

Comment: Did that. Didn't work.

Comment: Maybe checking out the console error would help? I tried changing it to a functional component but it didn't work.

Comment: @TobiasS Thanks for the help. The issue has been fixed. I was accidentally installing packages into the parent folder.